# How to load value of class using angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add class to span same as the value in ng-repeat.

My HTML code is

```
<div class="player">
    <span ng-repeat="cards in table.player.cards" class="a cards.card"></span>
</div>
```

Value of table.player.cards in controller is :

```
 table.player.cards = [{"card":"CQ"},{"card":"C3"},{"card":"C5"}]
```

I want to assign value of cards.card to span. How can i do it?

Comment: Err, `class="a {{cards.card}}"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
<div class="player">
    <span ng-repeat="cards in table.player.cards" class="a {{cards.card}}"></span>
</div>
```

You need to use the curly brackets to bring out the value of that object.